# How to make a static array containing information from all derived classes

Tags: c#, interface, derived-class

I have a interface called Species, and derived classes containing each species with literal information about the species. See below:

```
public interface Species
{
    string database { get; }
    string genus { get; }
    string binomialName { get; }
}

public class Monosiga_brevicollis : Species
{
    public string database { get {return "monosiga";} }
    public string genus { get {return "Choanoflagellatea";} }
    public string binomialName { get {return "Monosiga_brevicollis";} }
}

public class Amphimedon_queenslandica : Species
{
    public string database { get {return "queenslandica";} }
    public string genus { get {return "Porifera";} }
    public string binomialName { get {return "Amphimedon queenslandica";} }
}
```

This allows me to assign a species to an object, and then get information about where the database for that species is, or what genus the species is in.

How can I perform operation on all the derived classes of Speices. For example:

1) create a function:

```
public bool isSpecies(string binomial)
```

that allows me to check whether or not the inputted string is one of the pre-coded species by checking through the binomial names.

and 2) create a list

```
string[] allSpecies;
```

that contains all the binomial names in an array so I can use the array as default options for text boxes ect.

Comment: It seems like these should be instances of an implementation of the `ISpecies` interface, rather than separate classes.

Comment: you still need to store all the instances in a collection to be able to reference them by `ISpecies` interface type variable in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like these should be instances of an implementation of the ISpecies interface, rather than separate classes. Something like the following:

```
public class Species : ISpecies
{
    public string database { get; set; }
    public string genus { get; set; }
    public string binomialName { get; set; }
}

var speciesList = new List<ISpecies>()

var monosiga = new Species() {
    database = "monosiga",
    genus = "Choanoflagellatea",
    binomialName = "Monosiga_brevicollis"
}

speciesList.Add(monosiga);
```

Once you've filled up your list, you can enumerate the binomial names like so:

```
var names = speciesList.Select(s => s.binomialName);
```

You can also check whether a species is present in the list by doing:

```
bool IsSpecies(string binomialName) {
    _speciesList.Any(s => s.binomialName == binomialName);
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't allow me to have a Species object then, right? In another class, I would no longer be able to say `Species myspecies = new Monosiga_brevicollis()` and have access to the properties via `myspecies.database` that I have hard-coded into my Monosiga_brevicollis derrived class.

Comment: @MichaelMolter No, but if you create a collection like I demonstrated in the answer, and make it a static property, say of `Species`, you can still do this somewhere else: `Species myMonosigaSpecies = Species.SpeciesList.Single(s => s.binomialName == "Monosiga_brevicolis");`

Comment: I don't think this solution is elegant enough to implement. I lose all the convince of having an object and all the sudden have to write two lines of code every time I want to get at my properties. What I really want is a big global class, `Species`, where I can say, `Species.Monosiga.binomialName`, and get a hardcoded value back. At the same time. I wanted to be able to say, `Species.ListBinomialNames`, and get a collection of all the species names for comboboxes and such. My solution solves the first problem, yours solves the second. Neither works for my project.

Comment: @MichaelMolter What is wrong with `Species.GetBinomialName("Monosiga")`? Or even `Species.Get("Monosiga").binomialName`? Why is this not as good as `Species.Monosiga.binomialName`?

Comment: What I mentioned in my first comment--no object. This prevents me from passing species as an object for use in some other class. Say I have the class `Gene` constructed via `myGene = new Gene(string sequence, Species species)`. Without an object, I can not cleanly write `species.database` in the `Gene` class. I would have to pass the species to `Gene` as a string `myGene = new Gene(string sequence, string species)`, and every time I want to get information about the species in the `Gene` class I would have to reference `Species.Get(species).binomialName`. Its just seems messy.

Comment: What do you mean by "no object"? `Species.Get` would return a `Species` object. You can pass it into the constructor for `Gene` or wherever else you want.

Comment: @MichaelMolter There really isn't any reason you can't use instances instead of classes as I suggested and still expose a `Species.Monosiga` property that returns the relevant instance, but it seems the point of this conversation is now to shoot down every suggestion with a contrarian "this seems messy", which isn't a very good use of my time. Good luck.

Comment: That's not it at all. Interfaces are nearly brand new to me. I struggle to implement them, so I asked questions about the implementation of your solution. I have not seen an example of interfaces used in this way (usually as a template for classes of methods), and at my level of experience, your example does not get me to a solution. I do not understand how I can get global access to your `speciesList` object, nor how you declare a variable outside of a class. I would need either a more complete code sample of your idea, or a link to a similar usage of interfaces. I did not mean to offend.

Comment: @MichaelMolter Is something like this what you're looking for: http://ideone.com/RuD8MH? The `Species` class has static properties for each of your species and exposes an `All` property with a collection of all species.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62272/discussion-between-michael-molter-and-asad).